# Getting serialized data in another format

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, manytomanyfield

How can I get JSON in a new format such as `text/value` like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "doc2",
        "directions": [
       
            "mar", 
            "qwe"
           
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "directions": [
              "Surgery",
              "qwe"
        ]
    }
]
```

instead of:

```
[
    {
        "name": "doc2",
        "directions": [
            {
                "name": "mar"
            },
            {
                "name": "qwe"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "directions": [
            {
                "name": "Surgery"
            },
            {
                "name": "qwe"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here are my `models.py` and `serializers.py` modules:
**models.py**

```py
class Directions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=355)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Doctors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    directions = models.ManyToManyField(Directions)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializer.py**

```py
class DirectionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Directions
        fields = ('name',)


class DoctorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    directions = DirectionsSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Doctors
        fields = ('name', 'directions')
```

Comment: See: [StringRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for achieving this purpose:

### 1. Using [**`Custom relational fields`** <sup>[drf-docs]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields)

For your case, we could define a relational field to serialize a track to a custom string representation, using its ordering, title, and duration:

```py
class DirectionsSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.name

class DoctorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    directions = DirectionsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Doctors
        fields = ['name', 'directions']
```

This custom field would then serialize to the following representation:

```
[
    {
        "name": "doc2",
        "directions": [
       
            "mar", 
            "qwe"
           
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "directions": [
              "Surgery",
              "qwe"
        ]
    }
]
```

### 2. Using [**`StringRelatedField()`** <sup>[drf-docs]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

`StringRelatedField` may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its `__str__` method.

For your case, the following serializer:

```py
class DoctorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    directions = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Doctors
        fields = ['name', 'directions']
```

Would serialize to the following representation:

```
[
    {
        "name": "doc2",
        "directions": [
       
            "mar", 
            "qwe"
           
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "directions": [
              "Surgery",
              "qwe"
        ]
    }
]
```

This field is `read_only`.

Arguments:

- `many` - If applied to a to-many relationship, you should set this argument to `True`.